# Get Exactly 2 Characters Using Preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am having trouble with this expression:

```
preg_match('#<file(.*)source-language="(.){2}"(.*)>#Ui', $xliff, $matches);
```

I am trying to get the 'en' out of (exactly 2 a-z characters can be there):

```
<file src="index.php" source-language="en" date="2012-10-10">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the quantifier outside the capture section. You need to move the {2} inside the () so that both get captured.

```
'#<file(.*)source-language="(.{2})"(.*)>#Ui'
```

Comment: Both the extra asterisk and moving the quantifier inside the capture group works, but the extra asterisk means "0 or more" and the question specifically said "exactly 2". The asterisk would allow for any length to be captured.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('#<file(.*)source-language="(..)"(.*)>#Ui', $xliff, $matches);
```

I think this is a simpler way if you *know* this is going to be exactly two characters.  It could be more, though, so be careful.

You weren't capturing both characters before because the `{2}` was outside the capture.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea.  Try [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead.

Comment: If you're confident about the html's structure and aren't too worried about nested tags and the like, using regex is just fine.  It's faster and simpler than DOM.